# Trying to make a discord bot in python. When i tried to add cogs i ran into some problems

Tags: python, discord, bots

I've been trying to make a discord bot, which worked fine until I started using cogs.

There are 3 external files: fun.py, misc.py and mod.py which contain commands which should be loaded on_ready() through:

```
bot.load_extension(cog)
```

Each of the files has the following function at the end:

```
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(CogName(bot))
```

This is my code of the bot:

```
import json
import json
import os
import random
import sys

import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import Context

intents = discord.Intents.all()

if not os.path.isfile("config.json"):
    sys.exit("'config.json' not found! Please add it and try again.")
else:
    with open("config.json") as file:
        config = json.load(file)

@tasks.loop(minutes=1.0)
async def status_task() -> None:
    """
   Setup the game status task of the bot
   """
    statuses = ["Made by Samxel!", "M O O N", ":D"]
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(random.choice(statuses)))


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or(
    config["prefix"]), intents=intents, help_command=None)

cogs = ['cogs.fun', 'cogs.mod', 'cogs.misc'] # 'cogs' signifies the name of the folder, 'x' signifies the file name.



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as: {bot.user.name}')
    print(f'With ID: {bot.user.id}')

    for cog in cogs: # Looks for the cogs,
        await bot.load_extension(cog)  # Loads the cogs.
    return


@bot.event
async def on_command_error(context: Context, error) -> None:
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        minutes, seconds = divmod(error.retry_after, 60)
        hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
        hours = hours % 24
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Hey, please slow down!",
            description=f"You can use this command again in {f'{round(hours)} hours' if round(hours) > 0 else ''} {f'{round(minutes)} minutes' if round(minutes) > 0 else ''} {f'{round(seconds)} seconds' if round(seconds) > 0 else ''}.",
            color=0xE02B2B
        )
        await context.send(embed=embed)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Error!",
            description="You are missing the permission(s) `" + ", ".join(
                error.missing_permissions) + "` to execute this command!",
            color=0xE02B2B
        )
        await context.send(embed=embed)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Error!",
            description="I am missing the permission(s) `" + ", ".join(
                error.missing_permissions) + "` to fully perform this command!",
            color=0xE02B2B
        )
        await context.send(embed=embed)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Error!",
            description=str(error).capitalize(),
            color=0xE02B2B
        )
        await context.send(embed=embed)
    raise error



bot.run(config["token"], reconnect=True)
```

And this is the error message I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\Test.py 
2022-12-14 13:08:53 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2022-12-14 13:08:54 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 14a697b0d7cfc70b1666d995b6c92e78).
Logged in as: M O O N
With ID: 1052180600699748402
2022-12-14 13:08:56 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 934, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\cogs\fun.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Test import bot
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\Test.py", line 84, in <module>
    bot.run(config["token"], reconnect=True)
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Users\lists\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 186, in run
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\Test.py", line 41, in on_ready
    await bot.load_extension(cog)  # Loads the cogs.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1012, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 937, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.fun' raised an error: RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
2022-12-14 13:08:56 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 934, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\cogs\fun.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Test import bot
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\Test.py", line 84, in <module>
    bot.run(config["token"], reconnect=True)
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Users\lists\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 186, in run
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\Test.py", line 41, in on_ready
    await bot.load_extension(cog)  # Loads the cogs.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1012, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 937, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.fun' raised an error: RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
C:\Users\lists\PycharmProjects\MOONBOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:414: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.run.<locals>.runner' was never awaited
  await self.on_error(event_name, *args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Thanks for any help!

I've tried removing the on_command_error bot event and I also tried different methods to load the cog extensions... Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

try to `bot.load_extension(cog)`
without await

Comment: I get the error:

`"RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  bot.load_extension(cog)  # Loads the cogs.
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"`

Even if I put it outside the async, I still get the same error.